# User Saving a Customisable Template in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF xaml template and associated code behind with a variety of controls. The user can move these controls around so that one has the layout that one desires. However, once the user restarts the program, the controls return to their original locations. How do I make it so that the user can save the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save, reload the layout (`xaml`):

1. After the user changes the layout *[on `Window Closing` event]*, You can **save a XAML file base changed layout using [`XamlWriter` static class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx)**. In fact you serialize the container control and save it in a file.
2. Also you need some codes *[in the window constructor after `InitializeComponent()`]* to **reload serialized layout** of the container control [and its controls] from the file.

I put a sample (wrote by [Matt Searles](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/matt%20searles/?ws=usercard-mini)), [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65a2064f-2d6a-4ecc-8076-60c72cb7070d/wpf-c-save-controls-created-at-runtime?forum=wpf):

```
<StackPanel>
    <WrapPanel x:Name="wrapPanel1" Height="200"></WrapPanel>
    <Button Click="AddButton">Add Button</Button>
    <Button Click="SaveButtons">Save Buttons</Button>
    <Button Click="ReloadButtons">Reload Buttons</Button>   
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// Add a button to wrapPanel1
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void AddButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create the Button.
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Height = 50;
    button.Width = 100;
    button.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
    button.Content = "Click Me";

    wrapPanel1.Children.Add(button);
}

/// <summary>
/// Save wrapPanel1 to AA.xaml
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void SaveButtons(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder outstr = new StringBuilder();

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;


    XamlDesignerSerializationManager dsm = new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(XmlWriter.Create(outstr, settings));
    dsm.XamlWriterMode = XamlWriterMode.Expression;

    XamlWriter.Save(wrapPanel1, dsm);
    string savedControls = outstr.ToString();

    File.WriteAllText(@"AA.xaml", savedControls);
}

/// <summary>
/// Reload the buttons in AA.xaml
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void ReloadButtons(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(@"AA.xaml");
    string text = sR.ReadToEnd();
    sR.Close();

    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(text);
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

    WrapPanel wp = (WrapPanel)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

    wrapPanel1.Children.Clear(); // clear the existing children

    foreach (FrameworkElement child in wp.Children) // and for each child in the WrapPanel we just loaded (wp)
    {
        wrapPanel1.Children.Add(CloneFrameworkElement(child)); // clone the child and add it to our existing wrap panel
    }           
}

/// <summary>
/// Clone a framework element by serializing and deserializing it
/// </summary>
/// <param name="originalElement"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
FrameworkElement CloneFrameworkElement(FrameworkElement originalElement)
{
    string elementString = XamlWriter.Save(originalElement);

    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(elementString);
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    FrameworkElement clonedElement = (FrameworkElement)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

    return clonedElement;
}
```